# Google SignIn Screen Android Issue

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to use Google sign in my app.. I can successfully login if any existing account is used for logging but if I click on "Add account" and then add a new account then the account gets added (in device accounts section) but the app gets struck on a transparent dim screen and when the user clicks on it I get a callback error as  "Internal Server Error".
Any one has solution for this??

```
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

This the code I execute when user click on sign in button